# Client credential Oauth flow - Azure B2C

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Does Azure B2C support the Client Credentials OAUTH flow. I am trying to implement programmatic (non-interactive) login via Azure B2C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Azure B2C supports Resource Owner Password Credential (ROPC) user flow.

Please refer to Microsoft Documentation here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports this. There is an article and example application in the documentation: [Azure AD B2C: Use the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).